# Passing cookies from domain to sub domain

Tags: java, cookies, subdomain

I have a site with domain `www.foo.com` and we used to save our cookies with `www.foo.com`.
From now on we want to add sub domain to our site `test.foo.com` and because of that i can't 
get to the old cookies that used to be save on `www.foo.com`.

So I changed the cookies to by more general `.foo.com`, but i still can't get to old visitors with `www.foo.com`.

Is there is a way to solve it?  (client/server side)

Answer (score 1):

Just bind your cookies to the domain `.foo.com` instead of `www.foo.com`. The dot prefix acts as a wildcard, making your cookies visible across subdomains.

Comment: I edited my question. "So I changed the cookies to by more general '.foo.com', but i still can't get to old visitors with 'www.foo.com'."
What i can do with that problem?

Comment: your answer that you suggest is good for new users not for old users... so its not a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Domain in Cookies properties like Domain=xx.Domain.com this is Suggestion 1

and Second way is by make a page like CookiesManipulation.Aspx in the Sub Domain and Pass the Cookies ID and Value to that page like xx.Domain.Com/CookiesManipulation.Aspx ?UserName=Choop.

[Web site Can help you](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_internet/article.php/c19417)

I hope that I have help u.